# Moving my Visual Studio C++ project to 32 bit system from 64 bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

So I got a new desktop computer and I decided that I wanted to port my project over to it. The problem is my desktop is 32 bit and my laptop is 64 bit. My laptop therefore has SysWOW64 yet my desktop doesn't. Therefore I'm getting errors when I try to run my project about missing .dlls which are in System32 on the desktop. Note: I also upgraded to Visual Studio 2012 from 2010. I'm wondering how I can set up my project to look into System32 instead of SysWOW64 on my desktop computer. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to run the program compiled in the old pc in the new one? or trying to recompile it again? If the later, have you tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding it all? Are you using the right library dlls in the new pc?

Comment: By default, a 32 bit application will search for .dll's in System32 on a 32 bit OS and SysWOW64 on a 64 bit OS. A 64 bit application will search for .dll's in System32. The question is, why is your application looking for SysWOW64 when running on a 32 bit OS?

Comment: I'm trying to run the program the I compiled with Visual Studio 2010 on  my laptop, on my desktop computer with Visual Studio 2012. The problem is I think it's trying to find the .dlls in SysWOW64 which is only found on 64 bit systems like my laptop, rather than System32 which is found on the 32 bit system like my desktop computer.

Comment: If the program was compiled as 64bit in the 64bit OS and the destination pc is 32bit I don't think you'll be able to run the program. You'll have to recompile the program.

Comment: Well I tried to compile my project which was made on a 64 bit system, on my 32 bit desktop computer. It gives me errors when I try to run saying that it's missing files that could be found in SysWOW64 on the 64 bit OS but can be found in System32 on the 32 bit OS. It says the files aren't on the computer yet they are but just in a different location than the project was looking in before.

Comment: It's working fine except it's searching in the wrong place for the .dlls. Surely there is a way to make it search System32 rather than sysWOW64?

Comment: The first step would be analyzing your problem. Since you don't know what really is failing you should get [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and load your application. It will show you which modules could not be found and - most importantly - also lists their dependencies. This should help you get a clear picture of where things go wrong.

Comment: What are the missing files? System files or part of a library your project is using? Are the paths hard-coded in your project settings?

Comment: I think they are Visual Studio .dlls They are like MSVCP100D.dll,  MSVC100D.dll,  MSVCP110D.dll etc.

Comment: Those are the [Visual C++ Libraries](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555). If this application is just for you, simply install them on the client machine. If you plan on publishing your application you need to ship those .dll's and install them to the application directory. As an aside, those .dll's aren't part of Visual Studio but rather Visual Studio's C/C++ implementation. They are required for every C/C++ application built with Visual Studio (unless you explicitly specified /NODEFAULTLIB in the linker settings).

Comment: I got it. It was pretty weird. Some of the files were missing from my desktop that were needed yet I had them on my laptop. I just transferred the files via a cd to my desktop and it's working now. Thanks! Tim would you mind posting your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Tim more to the point, those are MS Visual C/C++ **Debug** DLL's (note the big **D** at the tail of the name), which will not be on any target client system unless proper development tools are installed. Nor are they installed by the stock redist package for a given VS-Runtime. The *release* version of said DLL's will be present, however, and should be in the proper location assuming they either came with the OS or were installed as an MSI-redist package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing .dll's are the Visual C++ Libraries required for applications developed using Visual Studio. They are installed as part of a Visual Studio install. To run an application on a system where Visual Studio is not installed you have to manually install them:

- For applications built with VS 2010: [Download link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555)
- For applications built with VS 2012: [Download link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

---

Edit: The missing .dll's were in fact the *Debug* versions of the Visual C++ Libraries. Those aren't available as a separate download. To resolve this issue the following options are available:

- Pragmatic: Compile a *Release* build and install the release libraries linked to above on the target machine.
- Install Visual Studio on the target machine which will install the *Debug* libraries as well.
- As a last resort, copy the *Debug* .dll's from a machine with a Visual Studio installation to the client machine.

Comment: He might consider linking up a **Release** build when following through on this, as the libraries he's mentioned are all **Debug** dependencies.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for the comment. I updated the answer to include possible solutions to satisfy the _Debug_ library dependencies. Good call.